# How to compress folder using ms resource kit tools?

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, zip

I have a folder "A" which contains b.txt, c.txt, and another folder B inside it. I want to compress folder A as A.zip. So that b.txt, c.txt and folder B resides inside A.zip. I tried it using windows resource toolkit but i coudn't do this

```
compress -Z *.*  C:\A.zip
```

i use above command in windows command line but it gives me error saying A.zip is not a valid destination directory. i use this http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en tool kit to use compress command in windows.
 Please help. Here I can’t use any other application because I can’t install anything in this machine.